# JCombobox adding different color to each item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a doubt on Jcombobox...
for example,
i have a gui which contains a jcombo box and a button...
In  Jcombo box  ,i have added string array object like color 1,color 2 ,color 3:
String[] colors = {"Color 1","Color 2","Color 3"}.and i can select color when clicked  the button by using of colorchooser and it will apply into the button only....
But i want to setforeground color to "Color 1" ,"Color 2" in tat combo box..
       for ex: if i select color as red through button,it should be applied foreground color on jcombobox only " SELECTED ITEM" only(example Color 1 should be displayed as RED,others  should be default color!

...I am new one to Java...if anyone knows,plz help me..
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can provide your own renderer to the JComboBox by implementing `ListCellRenderer`.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer